# How to copy files from directory meeting certain criteria

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to copy files from directory `A` to directory `B`. But I want to copy only files that have lower size then `X` *and* don't have file extensions specified in file `extension.txt`.

My main problem here is, I don't want to delete unwanted files after coping - I want to copy just files I need, using `bash` script.

Any ideas?

Comment: `find` might be a good start. What have you tried so far?

Comment: mainly "for" loop, which was a disaster... also i tried to "ls" and "cp" with flags, but it didnt worked :/

Comment: Can you post a sample of the `extention.txt` file?

Comment: i. e.: txt xy tar

Comment: Please post the scripts that you tried to write so far. And post an example for your extensions file properly formatted in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A extended version of @mihver1's answer. Have a look at `man find` if you want to understand this thoroughly.

```
#!/bin/bash
X=1000c # or what ever your size limit is
find_args=()
for ext in $(cat extensions.txt); do
  find_args=( "${find_args[@]}" -o -name "*.$ext" )
done
find_args=( -type f -size -$X -not \( -false "${find_args[@]}" \) )
# first try it
find directory_A "${find_args[@]}" -print
# if that looks fine, copy the files
find directory_A "${find_args[@]}" -exec cp {} direcotry_B +
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# assuming that extensions.txt looks like:
# *.txt
# *.csv
# *.img

X=your_size
pushd directoryA
rsync --exclude-from=extensions.txt $(find . -type f -size -${X}c) directoryB/
popd
```

Comment: This is buggy if files in directoryA have spaces is the file names.

Comment: @Lucas True, but it's a good start. Maybe add `--max-size` option, or use `--from0 --files-from`.